# Remove last symbol from regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tried to create a slug using regex, but at the last character I tried to input symbols like `hello world!`

this is my regex

```
slug.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/gi, "-")
```

A result like this

```
hello-world-
```

this is the result I was expecting

```
hello-world
```

so guys I tried to replace/remove the last symbol from my string
any solution guys thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
slug = slug.replace(/^[^A-Z0-9]+|[^A-Z0-9]+$|([^A-Z0-9]+)/gi, (x,y) => y ? '-' : '');
```

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
let slug = "!hello world!"
slug = slug.replace(/^[^A-Z0-9]+|[^A-Z0-9]+$|([^A-Z0-9]+)/gi, (x,y) => y ? '-' : '');
console.log(slug);
```

*Details*:

- `^[^A-Z0-9]+` - find one or more non-alphanumeric chars at the start of string (and remove this match)
- `|` - or
- `[^A-Z0-9]+$` - find one or more non-alphanumeric chars at the end of string (and remove this match)
- `|`- or
- `([^A-Z0-9]+)` - find and capture one or more non-alphanumeric chars  anywhere else in the string and replace with `-`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of replacing everything except `A-Z0-9` with a `-`, you could get all the `A-Z0-9` parts using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them with `-`

```js
const slugify = str => str.match(/[A-Z0-9]+/gi)?.join('-')

console.log(slugify("hello world!"))

console.log(
  ["¿Lorem ipsum?", "1 sheep 2 sheep", "UPPERCASE a1pha-numeric"].map(slugify)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the result you're looking for is `hello-world`, you'll neither need a second `replace` or to pass a function as the second `replace` parameter.

The second `replace` is quite straightforward, so I'd probably go with that.

```
result = slug.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/gi, "-").replace(/^-|-$/g, "");
```

```js
const slug = "hello world!";
const result = slug.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/gi, "-").replace(/-$/, "");
console.log(result);
```

`^-|-$` is an *alternation* between `^-` and `-$`, which matches either alternative, so that regular expression replaces any leading `-` (`^-`) or any trailing `-` (`-$`) with nothing. You need the `g` in case there are both leading and trailing `-`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, will it apply to all symbols?

Comment: @DickiMaulanaYusuf - Your `replace` replaces everything that isn't `A-Z0-9` with `-` (creating `hello-world-`). The second replace then replaces any final `-` with nothing (`hello-world-` => `hello-world`). So yes, effectively.

Comment: In a more general case, I think it should look like `result = slug.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/gi, "-").replace(/^-|-$/g, "");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Good point, I was focussing just on the trailing, but handling leading is important too. Done, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The other way around is matching all allowed and joining with a `-`

```js
let slug = "hello world!";
slug = slug.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi).join("-");
console.log(slug);
```